# Unmet dependencies while installing RISC pre-reqs

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, java, dependencies

I am installing pre-reqs to get a risc environment set up on my local ubuntu machine using a tutorial. However, I run into errors with these 2 dependencies. Can anyone guide me as to how I can fix these?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tzdata-java : Depends: tzdata (= 2019a-0ubuntu0.14.04) but 2022a-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 usrmerge : Conflicts: libpng12-0 (< 1.2.54-4~) but 1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 is to be installed
```

Comment: You are using a wrong tutorial. You need to fix dependencies version to correct ones.

Comment: How exactly can I fix dependencies version? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling tzdata with no luck. Thank you for any help!

Comment: It is unclear what tutorial you are using. It is probably too old. You are trying to install some packages (unclear why) that require specific ubuntu packages& tzdata-java version`2019a-0ubuntu0.14.04` and libpng12-0 version `< 1.2.54-4~`. But Ubuntu repositories have other versions. Which version of Ubuntu you are using?